# Escritura de archivo en Java

Tags: java

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo a tocar algo de código en Java y haciendo unas pruebas no consigo seguir adelante.
Lo que quiero hacer es escribir en un archivo a traves de un Path.

```
public class Pruebas2Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {

    Path path = Path.of("C:\\Users\\Oscar\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Pruebas2\\src\\Pruebas2\\pruebas.txt");
    
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Files.newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE),"UTF-8"));
    String ch = "Prueba de String";
    out.append(ch);
```

El tema es que la ruta la encuentra, me crea el documento pero no hay manera de escribir nada en el.
Tambien he probado añadir el APPEND a las opciones de de newOutputStream pero nada.

```
newOutputStream(path, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND),"UTF-8")
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Todo va en perfectas condiciones, solo falta agregar el cierre del *stream* `close()`

```
String ch="Prueba de String";
out.append(ch);
out.close();
```

O escribir el archivo usando [`write`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#write(java.lang.String)), con [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintWriter.html#append(char)) lo que se hace es añadir al *stream* una cadena de datos que finalmente va a escribirse, básicamente eso.

Para ver mas claramente la diferencia:

```
String ch="Prueba de String";
out.append(ch);
out.write("\nOtra nueva linea String de prueba");
out.close();
```

Asi el archivo en cuestión va a contener:

```
Prueba de String
Otra nueva linea String de prueba
```

Answer (score 0):

Era por el close().
Se ve que hasta que no se cierra el Stream no vuelca los datos.
Me estaba volviendo loco, muchas gracias.